# How to Write Route URL inside Javascript Laravel Blade?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my route, having 2 parameters,

```
url: '{{ route('datatable.getaccess', [$room->id_project , $room->id]) }},
```

if write like that will shown : `xxxxxx?xxxxxx` , that have ***question mark*** *beetwen id_project to $id* ,
how to write correctly? because that should **"/"** slash

Thank you.

Comment: What does that route look like in your `web.php` routes file?

Comment: I guess its perfect. your `route` is having one `route parameter` and other value is appended as `query parameter`

Comment: @kerbholz  `Route::get('viewroom/{id_project}/{id}', 'RoomController@show');` 
like that

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... sorry i  don't get your answer, whats that mean ? my route have 2 paramters ,

Comment: Where is `route name` ? It should be like this `Route::get('viewroom/{id_project}/{id}', 'RoomController@show')->name('datatable.getaccess');`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... my goodness how stupid  i'am , thank you solve the problem, i confuse have two route , i should delete one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string placeholders for javascript.

```xml
<input type="hidden" id="_room_id" value="{{ $room->id }}">
<input type="hidden" id="_room_project_id" value="{{ $room->id_project }}">
```

```js
let project_id = $('#_room_project_id').val(); // or document.getElementById('_room_project_id').value if you're not using JQuery
let id = $('#_room_id').val();                 // or document.getElementById('_room_id').value if you're not using JQuery
let url = "{{ route('datatable.getaccess', [':project_id', ':id']) }}".replace(':project_id', project_id).replace(':id', id);
```

This looks wrong but it works since we're passing strings to the route helper (which in turn produces a string)

```
route('datatable.getaccess', [':project_id', ':id'])
// 'viewroom/:project_id/:id'
```

so

```js
let url = "{{ route('datatable.getaccess', [':project_id', ':id']) }}".replace(':project_id', project_id).replace(':id', id);
```

is equivalent to

```js
let url = "viewroom/:project_id/:id".replace(':project_id', project_id).replace(':id', id);
```

Comment: this has realy helped a bunch for me